# Static variables across sessions

Tags: php, session

In ASP.NET if I declare a variable (or object) static (or if I make a singleton) I can have it persist across multiple sessions of multiple users (it it registered in a *server* scope) so that I don't have to initialize it at every request.

Is there such a feature in PHP? Thanks

Comment: Is this a use case for Redis?

Answer (score 7):

You can set up APC and use the apc_store and apc_fetch functions.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php

Comment: The link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with a PHP extension (written in C).

But if you want to write it in PHP, no. The best alternative is to write the variable to a file (file_put_contents()) at the end of each request, and open it at the start of each request (file_get_contents()).

That alternative isn't going to work for high volume sites because the processes will be doing read/write at the same time and the world will go all BLAAA-WOOO-EEE-WOHHH-BOOOM.

Comment: *`BLAAA-WOOO-EEE-WOHHH-BOOOM`?*  That's bad, right? 

Answer (score 4):

That doesn´t exist in PHP, however, you can serialize the data and put it either in a file on your hard drive or in /dev/shm/. You can also use memcache.

If you put your data in /dev/shm/ or use memcache the data *will disappear* on reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no. PHP's `static` keyword is limited to the current script instance only.

To persist data across script instances for the same session, you would use the  [**session handling**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) features.

To persist data across sessions, you would have to use something like [**memcache**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php), however that requires additional set-up work on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony and other frameworks uses **"PHPFastCache"** who supports a wide range of drivers for caching data including APC, SQLite, MongoDB or simply your file system.

You can donwnload it at https://github.com/PHPSocialNetwork/phpfastcache

Here is an example with file caching :

```
use Phpfastcache\Helper\Psr16Adapter;

$defaultDriver = 'Files';
$Psr16Adapter = new Psr16Adapter($defaultDriver);

// Setter action
if(!$Psr16Adapter->has('test-key')) {
    $data = 'lorem ipsum';
    $Psr16Adapter->set('test-key', 'lorem ipsum', 300); // kept in cache for 300 seconds (5 minutes)
}

// Getter action
else {
    $data = $Psr16Adapter->get('test-key');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Session Storage for this purpose, if you use the same sessionId for all sessions.

```
session_id('xyz');
session_start();
for ($i=0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    $_SESSION['counter'] = isset($_SESSION['counter']) ? $_SESSION['counter'] + 1 : 0;
}
echo "<br>session_id(): ".session_id() . "<br>counter: ".$_SESSION["counter"];
```

Try this script with 2 browsers and you will see that this method shares the data across both browsers - and is very, very fast.

Answer (score -1):

you could store serialized copies of an object inside session

```
class test{
  private static $instance;
  public property;
  private __construct(){}
  public getInstace(){
    if(!self::$instance){
      self::$instance = new test;
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }
}

$p = test->getInstance();
$p->property = "Howdy";
$_SESSION["p"] = $p;
```

next page

```
$p = $_SESSION["p"];
echo $p->property; // "Howdy"
```

Comment: IMO this shares the variable only between pages of the same session: it isn't helpful for sharing between multiple sessions or multiple users.

Comment: is an old answer, nowadays i would recommend to write a module, there are many options like C or C++ for writing with ease a compiled shared module.